# Canvas to 32bit packed ARGB

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, xlib

I have a html5 canvas element and I'm trying to get an array of ARGB data (32bit packed data, for use with x11/xorg/xlib). I don't know how to do this though.

For example this is what the data should look when processed (this here contains a `16x 16` image and a `32x32` image):

```
var 32BitPackedARGB = [16, 16, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 338034905, 3657433343, 0, 184483840, 234881279, 3053453567, 3221225727, 1879048447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1224737023, 3305111807, 3875537151,0, 0, 2063597823, 1291845887, 0, 67109119, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 50266112, 3422552319, 0, 0, 3070230783, 2063597823, 2986344703, 771752191, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3422552319, 0, 0, 3372220671, 1509949695, 704643327, 3355443455, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 3422552319, 0, 134152192, 3187671295, 251658495, 0, 3439329535, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3422552319, 0, 0, 2332033279, 1342177535, 167772415, 3338666239, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 3422552319, 0, 0, 436207871, 3322085628, 3456106751, 1375731967, 4278255360, 4026597120, 3758161664, 3489726208, 3204513536, 2952855296, 2684419840, 2399207168, 2130771712, 1845559040, 1593900800, 1308688128, 1040252672, 755040000, 486604544, 234946304, 4278255360, 4043374336, 3774938880, 3506503424, 3221290752, 2952855296, 2667642624, 2399207168, 2130771712, 1862336256, 1627453957, 1359017481, 1073805064, 788591627, 503379721, 218169088, 4278255360, 4043374336, 3758161664, 3506503424, 3221290752, 2952855296, 2684419840, 2415984384, 2130771712, 1862336256, 1577123584, 1308688128, 1040252672, 755040000, 486604544, 218169088, 4278190335, 4026532095, 3758096639, 3489661183, 3221225727, 2952790271, 2667577599, 2415919359, 2130706687, 1862271231, 1593835775, 1325400319, 1056964863, 771752191, 520093951, 234881279, 4278190335, 4026532095, 3758096639, 3489661183, 3221225727, 2952790271, 2667577599, 2415919359, 2130706687, 1862271231, 1593835775, 1325400319, 1056964863, 771752191, 503316735, 234881279, 4278190335, 4026532095, 3758096639, 3489661183, 3221225727, 2952790271, 2684354815, 2399142143, 2130706687, 1862271231, 1593835775, 1325400319, 1040187647, 771752191, 520093951, 234881279, 4294901760, 4043243520, 3774808064, 3506372608, 3221159936, 2952724480, 2684289024, 2399076352, 2147418112, 1862205440, 1593769984, 1308557312, 1040121856, 771686400, 503250944, 234815488, 4294901760, 4060020736, 3758030848, 3506372608, 3221159936, 2952724480, 2684289024, 2415853568, 2130640896, 1862205440, 1593769984, 1308557312, 1040121856, 771686400, 503250944, 234815488, 4294901760, 4043243520, 3774808064, 3489595392, 3237937152, 2952724480, 2684289024, 2415853568, 2147418112, 1862205440, 1593769984, 1325334528, 1056899072, 788463616, 503250944, 234815488, 32, 32, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 268369920, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 1509949695, 3120562431, 4009754879, 4194304255, 3690987775, 2130706687, 83886335, 0, 50331903, 1694499071, 3170894079, 3992977663, 4211081471, 3657433343, 1879048447, 16777471, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3087007999, 2281701631, 1191182591, 1040187647, 2030043391, 4127195391, 2566914303, 0, 16777471, 3254780159, 2181038335, 1191182591, 973078783, 2030043391,4177527039, 2130706687, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2214592767, 4093640959, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2298478847, 3909091583, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2214592767, 3607101695, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1946157311, 4093640959, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 536871167, 1191182591, 2281701631,3019899135, 637534463, 0, 0, 0, 100597760, 251592704, 33488896, 0, 3321889023, 2919235839, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2550137087, 4278190335, 4278190335, 3405775103, 570425599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2046820607, 4043309311, 620757247, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 33488896, 0, 0, 218104063, 1291845887, 3841982719, 3388997887, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1996488959, 4093640959, 1073742079, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1761607935, 4278190335, 150995199, 0, 0, 67109119, 2550137087, 3909091583, 889192703, 0, 0, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2181038335, 3925868799, 0, 0, 218104063, 3070230783, 3623878911, 570425599, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 805306623, 3288334591, 1795162367, 1040187647, 1023410431, 2231369983, 4211081471, 1694499071, 0, 369099007, 3456106751, 3825205503, 1174405375, 872415487, 872415487, 872415487, 872415487, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4293984270, 2046951677, 3422552319, 4110418175, 4177527039, 3405775103, 1409286399, 0, 0, 1409286399, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 4278190335, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760,4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 4294901760, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3053518592, 2936078080, 2801860352, 2650865408, 2516647680, 2382429952, 2264989440, 2113994496, 1996553984, 1862336256, 1728118528, 1577123584, 1459683072, 1325465344, 1191247616, 1040252672, 922812160, 771817216, 637599488, 503381760, 385941248, 234946304, 100728576, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3724607232, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3070295808, 2936078080, 2801860352, 2667642624, 2516647680, 2399207168, 2264989440, 2130771712, 1996553984, 1845559040, 1728118528, 1593900800, 1459683072, 1308688128, 1191247616, 1057029888, 922812160, 788594432, 637599488, 503381760, 369164032, 234946304, 117505792, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3053518592, 2919300864, 2801860352, 2650865408, 2533424896, 2399207168, 2264989440, 2113994496, 1996553984, 1862336256, 1728118528,1593900800, 1459683072, 1325465344, 1191247616, 1040252672, 906034944, 771817216, 654376704, 503381760, 369164032, 234946304, 117505792, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3858824960, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3070295808, 2936078080, 2801860352, 2667642624, 2533424896, 2382429952, 2264989440, 2130771712, 1979776768, 1862336256, 1728118528, 1577123584, 1442905856, 1325465344, 1191247616, 1040252672, 922812160, 771817216, 637599488, 503381760, 369164032, 234946304, 100728576, 4278255360, 4144037632, 4009819904, 3875602176, 3741384448, 3607166720, 3472948992, 3338731264, 3204513536, 3070295808, 2919300864, 2801860352, 2667642624, 2533424896, 2399207168, 2264989440, 2113994496, 1996553984, 1862336256, 1728118528, 1593900800, 1442905856, 1342241795, 1174470400, 1057029888, 906034944, 788594432, 654376704, 503381760, 385941248, 251723520, 100728576, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3741319423, 3623878911, 3472883967, 3338666239, 3221225727, 3070230783, 2952790271, 2818572543, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2264924415, 2147483903, 1996488959, 1862271231, 1728053503, 1593835775, 1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951,385876223, 251658495, 117440767, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3741319423, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3221225727, 3087007999, 2936013055, 2801795327, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2281701631, 2130706687, 1996488959, 1862271231, 1728053503, 1593835775,1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951, 385876223, 234881279, 100663551, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3758096639, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3221225727, 3087007999, 2936013055, 2801795327, 2667577599, 2550137087, 2415919359, 2264924415, 2130706687, 1996488959, 1862271231, 1728053503, 1593835775, 1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 503316735, 369099007, 251658495, 100663551, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3758096639, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3204448511, 3087007999, 2936013055, 2818572543, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2264924415, 2130706687, 1996488959, 1879048447, 1728053503, 1593835775, 1459618047, 1325400319, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951, 385876223, 251658495, 117440767, 4278190335, 4160749823, 4026532095, 3892314367, 3758096639, 3623878911, 3489661183, 3355443455, 3221225727, 3087007999, 2952790271, 2818572543, 2667577599, 2533359871, 2399142143, 2264924415, 2147483903, 2013266175, 1862271231, 1744830719, 1610612991, 1476395263, 1342177535, 1191182591, 1056964863, 922747135, 788529407, 654311679, 520093951, 385876223, 251658495, 100663551, 4294901760, 4160684032, 4026466304, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3623813120, 3489595392, 3355377664, 3237937152, 3103719424, 2952724480, 2818506752, 2684289024, 2550071296, 2415853568, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1878982656, 1744764928, 1593769984, 1476329472,1325334528, 1207894016, 1056899072, 939458560, 788463616, 654245888, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 117374976, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3640590336, 3506372608, 3355377664, 3221159936, 3086942208, 2952724480, 2818506752, 2701066240, 2550071296, 2415853568, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1878982656, 1727987712, 1610547200, 1476329472, 1325334528, 1191116800, 1073676288, 922681344, 788463616, 654245888, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 100597760, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3640590336, 3489595392, 3372154880, 3237937152, 3103719424, 2952724480, 2818506752, 2700935170, 2550071296, 2415853568, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1878982656, 1744764928, 1610547200, 1459552256, 1342111744, 1191116800, 1056899072, 922681344, 788463616, 671023104, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 100597760, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3640590336, 3489595392, 3372154880, 3237937152, 3086942208, 2969501696, 2818506752, 2684289024, 2550071296, 2432630784, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2013200384, 1862205440, 1744764928, 1610547200, 1476329472, 1342111744, 1191116800, 1056899072, 922681344, 788463616, 654245888, 520028160, 385810432, 251592704, 117374976, 4294901760, 4177461248, 4043243520, 3909025792, 3774808064, 3623813120, 3506372608, 3372154880, 3237937152, 3103719424, 2952724480, 2835283968, 2684289024, 2550071296, 2432630784, 2281635840, 2147418112, 2046492676, 1862205440, 1744764928, 1610547200, 1476329472, 1342111744,1207894016, 1056899072, 939458560, 788463616, 654245888, 536281096, 385810432, 251592704, 134152192];
```

This was my attempt:

http://jsfiddle.net/jqetamne/

```
var can = document.getElementById('mycan');
can.width = '16';
can.height = '16';
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 16);

var ARGBpixmap = [16, 16];
var image_data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
for (var x = 0; x < image_data.width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < image_data.height; y++) {
        var i = x * 4 + y * 4 * image_data.width;
        var r = image_data.data[i];
        var g = image_data.data[i + 1];
        var b = image_data.data[i + 2];
        ARGBpixmap.push(r + g + b);
    }
}

console.log(ARGBpixmap);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would tend to use `TypedArray` to make easier to convert from 8 to 32 bits integers (and more optimized):

```
// Getting pixels as a byte (uint8) array
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
var pixels8BitsRGBA = imageData.data;

// Reverting bytes from RGBA to ARGB
var pixels8BitsARGB = new Uint8Array(pixels8BitsRGBA.length + 8); // +8 bytes for the two leading 32 bytes integers
for(var i = 0 ; i < pixels8BitsRGBA.length ; i += 4) {
    pixels8BitsARGB[i+8 ] = pixels8BitsRGBA[i+3];
    pixels8BitsARGB[i+9 ] = pixels8BitsRGBA[i  ];
    pixels8BitsARGB[i+10] = pixels8BitsRGBA[i+1];
    pixels8BitsARGB[i+11] = pixels8BitsRGBA[i+2];
}

// Converting array buffer to a uint32 one, and adding leading width and height
var pixelsAs32Bits = new Uint32Array(pixels8BitsARGB.buffer);
pixelsAs32Bits[0] = can.width;
pixelsAs32Bits[1] = can.height;

console.log(pixelsAs32Bits);
```

---

EDIT : Unfortunately, this code is not reliable because it depends on your architecture (typed arrays depends on endianness) ...

I tried another way with bit-wise operators, but I get wrong results when changing the 32nd bit ...

That's crazy, but the only way I found to get this to work is not clean nor optimized:

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
var pixelsRGBA = imageData.data;
var pixelCount = pixelsRGBA.length / 4;

var pixelsARGBPacked = new Array(2 + pixelCount);
pixelsARGBPacked[0] = can.width;
pixelsARGBPacked[1] = can.height;
for(var i = 0 ; i < pixelCount ; i++) {
    pixelsARGBPacked[i+2] = parseInt(
          pixelsRGBA[i * 4 + 3].toString(16)
        + pixelsRGBA[i * 4    ].toString(16)
        + pixelsRGBA[i * 4 + 1].toString(16)
        + pixelsRGBA[i * 4 + 2].toString(16)
    , 16);
}

console.log(pixelsARGBPacked);
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much for such a fast reply and such a great answer. I'll test it out tomorrow and let you know how it works out! :)

Comment: Hey man I just tested it, the images are seeming quite blue :( Here is an image showing what it looks like. On the left its all blueish. And the original is on the right: http://i.imgur.com/CfrVnOB.png

Comment: A solid red filled image is coming out looking gray. The array is `[16, 16, 65535, 65535, ... ,65535]` basically all `65535`, I really appreciate this help!

Comment: @Noitidart I edited my answer. I'm not satisfied with the code, but it works :s .

Comment: Just tested it and it works much better thanks very much, I don't know anything about images I want to help :( But the thing is if its a red its not coming out red. A solid red fill is array of `16776960` which is exactly like before its all gray. I tested it with an actual icon and it looked okay for the most part. http://i.imgur.com/Gw4K1Nd.png

Comment: @SebastienC. +1 Nice answer.  A way to cleanly deal with "endian-ness" is to use javascript's `DataView`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView

Comment: Hey man I here's a better image, showing the new way still has some issue: its making transparent area in the middle its weird: http://i.imgur.com/21hCu7S.png Im going to read what markE posted and try to help out :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a neat trick to fix the strange behaviour at the 32:nd bit.
If you are convertig `argb` values to a regular argb int you have to do an unsigned right shift `>>>` with `0`. Then you force the value to become an unsigned int. Tested in nodejs.

```
var a = 0xFF, r = 0xFF, g = 0x00, b = 0xFF;
result1 = (((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((r & 0xff) << 16) | ((g & 0xff) << 8) | (b & 0xff)) >>> 0;
result2 = (((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((r & 0xff) << 16) | ((g & 0xff) << 8) | (b & 0xff));
```

`result1` will print `0xFFFF0000` and `result2` will print `-10000` when doing `.toString(16)` on them